# Camera.fit equivalent in Flutter google maps

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

On native iOS and Android version of Google Maps you can do something like this where you can specify the padding to be used on each edge around the bounds:

```
mapView?.animate(
                with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(
                    bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 250, right: 20)
                )
            )
```

I don't see the same option available on the Flutter GM. Only the option to set the padding for all sides:

```
controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding))
```

Is there a way to achieve bottom padding thats different to the top,left and right without the CameraUpdate.fit being available?